# do..while loop - not breaking when condition met

Tags: c, arrays, do-while, break

So with these few lines of code I want to keep storing inputs into an array until dot('.') is written. But when dot is actually written nothing happens, it just makes me put another input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    char array[MAX];
    int i = 0;

    do{
        scanf("%c", &array[i]);
        i++;

    }while(array[i] != '.');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're incrementing i after you've added the last value to the array, so the while condition will always be looking at the next (not yet stored) value in the array, not the last inserted?

Answer (score 2):

In a do..while loop, the do block is executed before the while condition is evaluated. That's the whole point.

You are filling `array[i]` with a scanned character, then by incrementing `i` you evaluate `array[i+1]` as if it were the input, which is actually at `array[i]`.

You probably want to swap this out for a normal for loop.

When debugging this sort of thing, you want to start with double checking if the condition you think is being met is actually being met, for example by debug printing the condition value. You could do that by printing `array[i]` at the very last line of your do block.

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing i before the check, so the value in that position is not the character you read, but the next (so whatever was in the array).